# Erro ao executar projeto de testes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, testes, testes-de-unidade, visual-studio-2015

Adicionei um projeto de testes em minha solution para testar os métodos de minha aplicação MVC.

Criei uma classe base, para as outras classes com testes herdarem da mesma, que contém a criação do contexto (`IdentityDbContext`).

Logo no ***constructor*** da classe base eu adicionei um ***breakpoint*** e no projeto de testes há apenas uma classe de testes, com um método apenas, e essa está herdando da classe base.

```
public abstract class BaseTest
{
    protected CustomContext Context;

    protected BaseTest()
    {
        Context = new CustomContext();  // um breakpoint é colocado aqui
    }
}
```

Coloquei um ***breakpoint*** no ***constructor*** da classe base exatamente na primeira linha onde deve instanciar o **contexto** do banco de dados. Mas ao rodar o ***debug*** do teste nem mesmo é executado essa linha, pois não para no ***breakpoint***, e um erro já é disparado.

> Managed Debugging Assistant 'DisconnectedContext' has detected a problem in 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 14.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW\te.processhost.managed.exe'.
>
> Additional information: Falha na transição para o contexto COM 0xaff5d8 para este RuntimeCallableWrapper com o seguinte erro: O objeto chamado foi desconectado de seus clientes. (Exceção de HRESULT: 0x80010108 (RPC_E_DISCONNECTED)). Normalmente isso ocorre porque o contexto COM 0xaff5d8 onde esse RuntimeCallableWrapper foi criado está desconectado ou está ocupado fazendo outra coisa. Liberando as interfaces do contexto COM atual (contexto COM 0xaff468). Isto pode causar corrupção ou perda de dados. Para evitar este problema, verifique se todos os contextos/apartamentos/threads COM se mantêm vivos e se estão disponíveis para a transição de contexto até que o aplicativo encerre totalmente os RuntimeCallableWrappers que representam componentes COM residentes neles.

Na janela ***Unit Test Session*** aparece a seguinte mensagem:

> Unable to create instance of class MeuProjeto.SubPasta.HomeControllerTest. Error: System.TypeLoadException: Método Set no tipo MeuOutroProjeto.Context.CustomContext do assembly MeuOutroProjeto, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null não tem uma implementação..
>
> em MeuProjeto.SubPasta.Base.BaseTest..ctor()
>        em MeuProjeto.SubPasta.HomeControllerTest..ctor()

Alguém sabe do que se trata e como eu poderia resolver?

Minha classe de Teste:
Nesse método nenhum ***breakpoint*** é acionado também:

```
[TestClass]
public class HomeControllerTest : BaseTest
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TentativaDeAcessoAoIndexComoAnonimo()
    {
        var usuario = Context.Users
            .SingleOrDefault(x => x.UserName == "Anonimo");

        if (usuario == null)
            throw new Exception(GetType().Name + ": Usuário inválido");

        Assert.AreEqual(usuario.Nome, "Anonimo", "Deu bug!");
    }
}
```

Código do contexto:

```
public class CustomContext : IdentityDbContext<Usuario>, IContext
{
    public CustomContext() : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
        Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
    }

    public DbSet<Classe> Classes { get; set; }
    ...

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<ManyToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();

        modelBuilder.Properties<string>().Configure(x => x.HasColumnType("varchar"));

        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ClasseConfiguration());
        ...

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>().ToTable("Usuarios");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Usuario>().ToTable("Usuarios");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().ToTable("Roles");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().ToTable("UserRoles");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim>().ToTable("UserClaims");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().ToTable("UserLogins");

        // para não criar o campo IdentityUser_Id
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>().HasMany(x => x.Roles)
            .WithRequired()
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.UserId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>().HasMany(x => x.Claims)
            .WithRequired()
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.UserId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>().HasMany(x => x.Logins)
            .WithRequired()
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.UserId);
    }
```

***Interface*** `IContext`:

```
public interface IContext
{
    DbChangeTracker ChangeTracker { get; }
    DbContextConfiguration Configuration { get; }
    Database Database { get; }
    IDbSet<IdentityRole> Roles { get; set; }
    IDbSet<Usuario> Users { get; set; }
    void Dispose();
    DbEntityEntry Entry(object entity);
    DbEntityEntry<TEntity> Entry<TEntity>(TEntity entity) where TEntity : class;
    bool Equals(object obj);
    int GetHashCode();
    Type GetType();
    IEnumerable<DbEntityValidationResult> GetValidationErrors();
    int SaveChanges();
    Task<int> SaveChangesAsync();
    Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken);
    DbSet Set(Type entityType);
    DbSet<TEntity> Set<TEntity>() where TEntity : class;
}
```

Comment: Que bizarro. Você pode colocar o código dessa classe de testes na sua pergunta?

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez, adicionado

Comment: Tem alguma coisa medonha do seu contexto. Pode colocar o código dele também na pergunta?

Comment: Bizarro mesmo.. eu então, tô boiando.. Adicionado. E obrigado por tentar ajudar!

Comment: Então, o que tem essa interface `IContext`? Possivelmente o problema está que tem algum elemento dentro dela que não foi implementado em `CustomContext`.

Comment: São métodos copiados de DbContext para facilitar a injeção..
Vou colocá-la também. Vou tentar sem ela.

Comment: Chegou à criação do Contexto e conseguiu instânciar.. mas no fim deu o mesmo erro.. Li em outros lugares que pode ser coisa de interface registrado em outros projetos sim. Deu o mesmo erro ao tentar executar o método de teste, na hora de entrar nele. E a mensagem de erro é a mesma... Complicou pra mim!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A mensagem de erro diz:

> Unable to create instance of class MeuProjeto.SubPasta.HomeControllerTest. Error: System.TypeLoadException: Método Set no tipo MeuOutroProjeto.Context.CustomContext do assembly MeuOutroProjeto, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null não tem uma implementação.

E sua interface `IContext` tem o seguinte:

```
public interface IContext
{
    ...
    DbSet<TEntity> Set<TEntity>() where TEntity : class;
}
```

O erro diz que este método não está implementado na sua classe. Por isso o erro.

Há várias maneiras de resolver. Eu tiraria a interface da classe do contexto em primeiro lugar e testaria sem ela. Depois faria os ajustes pra classe funcionar novamente com a interface.

Comment: Tirei a interface para testar e até aceitou instanciar o Contexto e entrou no método da classe de teste, mas deu o erro ao executar o `SingleOrDefault()`.

Comment: Bom, aí eu acho que já é caso pra outra pergunta.

Comment: Constrangedor.. ¬¬ .. problema resolvido após um `update-package` que atualizou o EF. Paciência.. Grato!